# Transformer regression model outputs NaN for input with all-True mask

Tags: python, pytorch, nan, transformer-model

I am training a Transformer model that does regression. The dataset consists of sequences of at most 6, but mostly <3, items. When a sequence only has `x` items, I mask out the last `6-x`. However, if and only if the transformer (either during or after training) gets the sequence of length 6 (there is only one), the output becomes `NaN`. In this case, the mask looks something like `[True, True, True, True, True]`. What is causing this? Maybe I am not applying the mask correctly?

Here's the model code:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.encoder_layer = nn.TransformerEncoderLayer(d_model=200,
                                                        nhead=1,
                                                        dim_feedforward=2,
                                                        dropout=0.1,
                                                        layer_norm_eps=1e-05,
                                                        batch_first=True,
                                                        norm_first=False)
        self.encoder = nn.TransformerEncoder(self.encoder_layer, num_layers=2)
        self.layer_norm = nn.LayerNorm(d_model)
        self.linear_layer = nn.Linear(d_model, 1)
        return

    def forward(self, src):
        mask = torch.sum(src,-1) != 0 # heuristic but works in this case
        encoded = self.encoder(src, src_key_padding_mask=mask) # is this correct?
        out = self.linear_layer(encoded.mean(dim=1))
        return out
```

I have tried normalizing/scaling the data, but the problem persisted.

Comment: In addition, what is the difference between applying a mask vs. having irrelevant items be zero vectors? There was no problem when I did the latter.